# How to change fault code in soap fault using interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

Have a problem with fault code in soap fault currently in looks like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001">
         <faultcode>ns0:B-NONUNIQUE-WORKORDERID</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Work order ID is not unique</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But i need it like this (without namespace prefix):

```
<faultcode>B-NONUNIQUE-WORKORDERID</faultcode>
```

What I already tried:

- first of all i intercept soap fault with spring aop and implement EndpointInterceptor to get messageContext(org.springframework.ws.context)
- message context has method "setResponse" - it suites me perfectly bit the API of WebServiceMessage and its subclasses is quite poor and i can't change the insides of response in that way
- tried other several ways but it got even worse.

Can anybody make a hint what to do to get and change fault code?
or to avoid namespace prefix appearance in the fault code.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of investigation i found quite ugly solution. First of all i have a spring interceptor in my xml config:

```
<sws:interceptors>
        <bean id="attachmentInterceptor"
              class="com.net.tel.interceptors.MessageInterceptor">
        </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

Interceptor implementation:

```
public class MessageInterceptor extends EndpointInterceptor {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NCOssNinasAttachmentInterceptor.class);

    private SoapMessageFactory soapMessageFactory;

    @Autowired
    private NCOssNinasAttachmentInterceptor(SoapMessageFactory soapMessageFactory) {
        this.soapMessageFactory = soapMessageFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        SaajSoapMessage message = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        final OutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(s);
        log.info("SOAP RESPONSE: " + s.toString());
        String modifiedMsg = faultCodeModifier(s.toString());
        log.info("MODIFIED RESPONSE: " + modifiedMsg);
        final InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(modifiedMsg.getBytes());
        SoapMessage m = soapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(is1);
        if (messageContext.hasResponse()) messageContext.clearResponse();
        messageContext.setResponse(m);
        log.info("NEW RESPONSE WAS SET");
    }
```

As you can see i'm getting response as a string and to modify it a wrote a simple (ugly) parser:

```
private String faultCodeModifier(String message) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] arr = message.split("<");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String b = arr[i];
            if (arr[i].contains("faultcode") && !arr[i].contains("/")) {
                String a = arr[i].split(">")[1];
                String c = a.split(":")[1];
                b = arr[i].split(">")[0] + ">" + c;
            }
            if (!"".equals(arr[i])) sb.append("<" + b);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And in the end i'm creating new response and inserting it in message context. All that had solved my issue by i'm not satisfied with it. If anybody has a better solution please share it.